# Need help with recognizing a sound source

Tags: sample

Hello everyone

I need a little help here, does anyone might recognize what's the soundsource of the sounds in this sample: https://soundcloud.com/pandroid77/sound-sample

I would be really grateful,
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Strings and percussion, plus reverb. Alternately, some synth patch.

Answer (score 0):

MY guess would be a cello, no percussion, with an artificial reverb that enforces the low-end a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would say percussion with a resonant reverb, maybe one of the Waves Enigma or Mondomod plugs used for resonance.

-Morten